# How to download image from web?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS i want download image to display it is working code but here lot of code duplication

```
let url = URL(string: iteminfo.imageUrl!)
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        if let data = data {
            print(data)
            self.imageViewItemPic.image  = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    let url2 = URL(string: iteminfo.cookerProfilePicUrl!)
    let urlRequest2 = URLRequest(url: url2!)
    let task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest2) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        if let data = data {
            print(data)
            self.imageViewCookerProfilePic.image  = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    task2.resume()
```

So I want to reuse my code but i unfortunately i can not reach my goal. there have no error and url is correct . every time goes else statement . i am missing something but what is that ?

```
        if let image = downlaodImage(urlImage: iteminfo.imageUrl){
            print("first \(image)")
              imageViewItemPic.image = image

        }else{
           print("first wrong......")
        }
        if let image =  downlaodImage(urlImage:  iteminfo.cookerProfilePicUrl){
            print("second \(image)")
             imageViewCookerProfilePic.image = image
        }
        else{
            print("second wrong......")
        }
```

Here is my method :

```
  func downlaodImage(urlImage : String?) -> UIImage?{
        var image : UIImage?
        let url = URL(string: urlImage!)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data {
               // print(data)

            image = UIImage(data: data)


            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return image
    }
```

*note: I am not sure is it best way or not . if it is not best practice feel free to guide me* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need of so much hassle. You have the `URL` of the image so you can simply download the image from the `URL`. For example:

```
func downloadImage(imageURL: String) {

    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        let data = NSData.init(contentsOf: NSURL.init(string: imageURL) as! URL)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let image = UIImage.init(data: data as! Data)
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** To reuse this code I would suggest to use extension of `UIImageView`. Here's an example:

```
extension UIImageView {

    func setImageFromURL(url: String) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {

            let data = NSData.init(contentsOf: NSURL.init(string: url) as! URL)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let image = UIImage.init(data: data as! Data)
                self.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this method whenever you want to set the image of an `imageView` from a `url` like this:

```
self.imageViewCookerProfilePic.setImageFromURL(url: "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNpKmjx1w3DRDZ9IXN81-uhSUA6qL6obkOthoUkb9RZkXf5pJ8")
```

Comment: could you check my question please .. I updated my code

Comment: did you check the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library?

Comment: @cristanlika of course it is possible but I'm trying to save you from trouble. However if you want to do it yourself I'll help you. Do you have any idea of `extensions`?

Comment: that's great. You can then do this very easily and in a very efficient way. I'm going to update my answer with the code that serves your purpose and is reusable too.

Comment: @cristanlika now check the answer.

Comment: if you have time could you tell me please when . 1st time loading the uitable cell. if paza1 image showing but when i touch then change the image . paza2 . what is going on here ?

Comment: sorry I don't get your point. Which `tableViewCell` are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Dude. You should learn some staff about async and sync code.
Here is the thing. Code in you `downloadImage` works synchronically, so it pass you `URLTask` and go straight to return, there you return you `image` variable, that is nil.
One of the solutions in to use callback block like this:

```
func downloadImage(urlImage : String?, complete: ((UIImage?)->Void)? = nil){

    let url = URL(string: urlImage!)
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if let data = data {
           complete?(UIImage(data: data))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
    { ...
        downloadImage(urlImage: "", complete: { image in
            if let image = image{
                self.imageViewItemPic.image = image
            }else{
                print("no image")
            }
        })
      ...
    }
```

You should read some tutorials about async code and web in swift. You could start with this [site](https://www.raywenderlich.com)

Comment: could you check my question please .. I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

`downlaodImage()` downloads an image asynchronously so

`if let image = downlaodImage(...) { ... }`

is always going to fail because program execution has continued before your response data has come back.

It would be easier just to set your images in the callback function closure of `downlaodImage()` as below by adding a `UIImageView` parameter to `downlaodImage()`. This way you can reduce the repetition of if else blocks by moving them to the `downlaodImage` function.

```
func downlaodImage(urlImage : String?, imageView: UIImageView) -> UIImage?{
    var image : UIImage?
    let url = URL(string: urlImage!)
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if let data = data {
           // print(data)

        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            imageView.image = image
        } else {
            print("failed to load image")
        }





        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return image
}
```

**Simplified code without if/else blocks**

```
downlaodImage(urlImage: "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNpKmjx1w3DRDZ9IXN81-uhSUA6qL6obkOthoUkb9RZkXf5pJ8", imageView: imageViewItemPic)

downlaodImage(urlImage: "https://www.dominos.co.nz/ManagedAssets/OLO/eStore/all/Product/NZ/P015/P015_ProductImage_Small_en_Default_20140203_105245.png", imageView: imageViewCookerProfilePic)
```

Comment: could you check my question please .. I updated my code